# How to use async / await when I need it embedded in a forEach() in javascript

Tags: json, promise, async-await, sequelize.js

I know this will not work the way I have it written and I am not seeing any answers that solve the problem for me. The code is too long to place here but I have included a link to a gist

https://gist.github.com/dhawkinson/41211d067ea91e0b7a5823067d2e39fe

My problem is this:

I get a list of ids to json files that must be read and converted to rows in Multiple SQL tables. The list comes from another json file in the form of an array of ids to the files I need to read and convert.

By requirement, there can be no rows with redundant data in the SQL tables. The ids to the SQL are auto generated. There are 3 categories of Entities in the API:

1. Learners -- Students who take Courses
2. Courses -- Training opportunities offered to Learners (they have children representing details)
3. Outcomes -- The intersection of a Learner, taking a Course, as of a specific Date (they have children representing details)

Both Learners and Courses may appear multiple time in Outcomes but only once for a specific Date. But, both Learners and Course may only appear once in the Learners and Courses tables, respectively (no redundancies).

My source data is 4 json Outcomes, matching the 4 ids in my list. The High-level view is as follows (format: Course_TimeStamp.json)

- id = 5sM5YLnnNMN_1525523468000.json (learner = daffy@duck.com)
- id = 5sM5YLnnNMN_1527517868000.json (learner = yogi@bear.com)
- id = 6tN6ZMooONO_1530730049000.json (learner = daffy@duck.com)
- id = 6tN6ZMooONO_1541011649000.json (learner = foghorn@leghorn.com)

When I parse and write the data I get:

- 3 Learner rows (as Expected)
- 3 Course rows (1 is redundant, not allowed)
- 4 Outcome rows (as expected)
- The children for both the Courses and Outcomes are being written as expected.

How do I solve this problem, given my constraints? I suspect the problem of redundancy can probably show up in the Learners table under some obscure circumstance, though it has not as yet. I am using the same approach for all the tables.

Help is appreciated. Sorry for the verbosity.

Comment: The problem description doesn't mention async or await, so it's not clear how the title relates to the question

Comment: I use async / await in the code as you will see if you look at the gist.

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code in the question please. Don't rely on external hosts.

Comment: That gist is over 250 lines long. You have to at least explain what part of the gist is relevant to the title and point to the line number that's causing you trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't use async/await with forEach**

> **REASON :** Because we can not use await inside synchronous function. As you can see “processArray” is async function. But anonymous
>   function that we use for forEach is synchronous. **[DO READ](https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795)**

```
questions.forEach((question) => {
    processCourseDetails(jsonData, question);
});
```

**You can use simple for loop** , like this

```
for(question of questions) {
    await processCourseDetails(jsonData, question);
}
```

> You can create a custom function to work like forEach with async/await
>   , **[DO READ](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)**

Comment: Thanks for this. I have run into a lot of articles, but not this one. I have bookmarked it and will study it in depth in the morning. Hope this does it.

Comment: @doug5solas , Okay sure :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can collect all the promises and then `Promise.all` them. That lets the promises run in parallel. `await Promise.all(questions.map(q => processCourseDetails(jsonData, q))`.

Comment: @Vivek Doshi: Thank you so much. I have been wrestling with this for quite awhile. I read the article and adapted the examples to my situation and it works brilliantly. All of my results are as expected. I am one grateful rookie.